# How do I prevent reduced mouse sensitivity during a screenshot on High Sierra?

Tags: mouse, screen-capture, high-sierra

### Steps to reproduce

Move the cursor using a mouse (not the trackpad) and note the cursor speed. Now Press `Command + Shift + 4`, which should change the cursor to a crosshair. Move the cursor again.

---

### Expected behavior

No change in mouse sensitivity

---

### Actual behavior

The mouse sensitivity is significantly lower (i.e. the cursor moves "slower"). Note that this *only occurs with an attached mouse*. The built-in trackpad sensitivity seems unaffected.

---

### System Information

- macOS High Sierra 10.13
- MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)
- Mouse: SteelSeries Sensei RAW

Comment: I can't replicate.  Can you try in Safe Mode or in a different user account to see if it's something specific to your environment?

Comment: Have you tried this with an Apple-branded mouse? Specs on this particular mouse indicate: "Scalable pointer speed from 90 up to 5670 in increments of 90 so you can be exact." Is any SteelSeries or other USB device software like USBOverdrive installed? If so, disable it and see what happens.

Comment: I have the SteelSeries Engine 3.9.0 driver and the SteelSeries ExactMouse Tool v1.0.3 (prevents mouse acceleration) installed. I looked for special settings (aside from sensitivity) in the driver but it appears that only `Sensitivity`, `Polling Rate`, button macros, and the LED lights are configurable. I tried disabling ExactMouse, but it did not change the screenshot behavior. I don't have another mouse handy at the moment, so I'm not sure how other devices would behave.

Comment: Updating to the latest SteelSeries Engine 3.11.4 did not have any effect.

Comment: @Allan I just created a new user account and it did not happen in that account. So it must be specific to my user. Definitely helpful. I might have run `defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1` at some point in the past... I will see if that's causing it. Otherwise it might be the driver software.

Comment: You may want to start by disabling (if applicable) items in "Login Items." 
 When you find the issue, post as an answer and I will upvote.   Wish I could assist more, but I can't replicate and can't see your environment to assist further.

Comment: Funny enough, I tried using an identical mouse (same brand and model #) and this did not happen. So it almost certainly seems like a bug in the driver software. When I have time I'll try uninstalling/reinstalling it as well as your other suggestions.

Comment: I'm getting this with a Logitech G403 after updating. 10.13, MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2014).

Comment: I can confirm that I also had this issue when I upgraded to 10.13 (High sierra). I use a Logitech G502 mouse. High Sierra had so many issues I had to downgrade to Sierra and everything works fine again.

Comment: @CgodLEY Did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the same problem with SteelSeries Engine 3.11.7 on High Sierra 10.13.1.

Comment: @kba No, I did not have time to narrow it down yet. It does seem specific to my user account though (see previous comments)

Comment: I noticed the slow-mo is more obvious on non-hidpi screen. On the retina screen, the acceleration feels *almost* the same during screenshot or not.